# spring mongotemplate query append an array is creating array of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

I need to append my field in mongodb

I am using below mongotemplate query for testing

```
List<String> dataList = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");

Update update = new Update();
     
update.push("mylist", dataList);
UpdateResult upResult = null;
query = new Query(Criteria.where("myId").is(appenModel.getMyId()));
try {
upResult = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, AppenModel.class);
logger.info("Updated Successfully");
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error("Update is failed", e);
}
```

for testing purpose I am calling above code multiple times but its getting appended in my collection as a extra array .

It is updating as Array of Array

```
{
_id:5d5d55cde95b5c58740ec2d4
myId:123
   mylist:[["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You","Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You","Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"]]
}
```

my expectation is

```
{
myId:123
_id:5d5d55cde95b5c58740ec2d4
mylist:["Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You","Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You","Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since pushAll is depreciated you have to use push and each together

```
update.push("mylist").each(dataList)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `pushAll()` instead of `push()`.

```
List<String> dataList = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");
Update update = new Update();
update.pushAll("mylist", dataList);
```

Comment: Push all is depreciated.. so can not use it .. but I don't know how to use push with each

Comment: @kcoder `update.push("mylist").each(dataList)`